# operation not allowed after ResultSet closed Part2

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc, resultset

Can someone explain why i get the "operation not allowed after ResultSet closed" error at the following code;

My db consists of two tables, consoles and hardware. Consoles table has 3 columns ( id, name and cost) while hardware has 4 columns (id, CPU, Memory and HDD).

When i reach to:

```
while(rs1.next())  
{
    a1 = rs1.getString(1);    
    b1 = rs1.getString(2);
    c1 = rs1.getString(3);    
    model1.addRow(new Object[]{a1,b1,c1});
}
```

the error pops up and i cant figure out why.

Code :

```
try
{    
    add = true;
    conn1 = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/test1?user=me&password=12345");
    conn3 = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/test1?user=me&password=12345");
    stmt1 = conn1.createStatement();
    stmt3 = conn3.createStatement();
    rs1 = stmt1.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM consoles");
    rs3 = stmt1.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM hardware");
    conn_pr1 = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/test1?user=me&password=12345");
    conn_pr3 = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/test1?user=me&password=12345");
    String sql1 = "INSERT INTO consoles (name,cost) VALUES (?,?)";
    String sql3 = "INSERT INTO hardware (CPU,Memory,HDD) VALUES (?,?,?)";
    ps1 =conn_pr1.prepareStatement(sql1);
    ps3 = conn_pr3.prepareStatement(sql3);
    str1 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Console name : ");
    if(!(str1 == null))
    {
        ps1.setString(1,str1);
        str2 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Cost : ");
    }
    if(!(str2 == null))
    {
        int2 = Integer.parseInt(str2); 
        ps1.setLong(2,int2);
        str3 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"CPU : ");
    }
    if(!(str3 == null))
    {
        str4 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Memory : ");
        ps3.setString(1,str3);
    }
    if(!(str4 == null))
    {
        str5 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"HDD : ");
        ps3.setString(2,str4);
    }
    if(!(str5 == null))
    {
        int3 = Integer.parseInt(str5); 
        ps3.setLong(3,int3);
    }

    if((!(str1 == null)) && (!(str2 == null)) && (!(str3 == null)) &&
       (!(str4 == null)) && (!(str5 == null)))
    {  //start if
        ps1.executeUpdate();
        ps3.executeUpdate();
        model1 = new DefaultTableModel();
        model3 = new DefaultTableModel();
        table1 = new JTable(model1);
        table3 = new JTable(model3);
        model1.addColumn("id");
        model1.addColumn("name");
        model1.addColumn("cost");
        model3.addColumn("id");
        model3.addColumn("CPU");
        model3.addColumn("Memory");
        model3.addColumn("HDD");

        while(rs1.next())  
        {
            a1 = rs1.getString(1);    
            b1 = rs1.getString(2);
            c1 = rs1.getString(3);    
            model1.addRow(new Object[]{a1,b1,c1});
        }

        while(rs3.next())  
        {
            a3 = rs3.getString(1);
            if (a3 != a)
                a3 = a;
            b3 = rs3.getString(2);
            c3 = rs3.getString(3);
            d3 = rs3.getString(4);  
            model3.addRow(new Object[]{a3,b3,c3,d3});
        }

        model1.fireTableDataChanged();
        table1.setCellSelectionEnabled(true);
        table1.setColumnSelectionAllowed(true);
        table1.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
        table1.setSurrendersFocusOnKeystroke(true);
        table1.setBounds(10,45,461,360);
        frame.getContentPane().remove(tablecons);
        frame.getContentPane().add(table1);
        model1.fireTableDataChanged();
        model3.fireTableDataChanged();
        table3.setCellSelectionEnabled(true);
        table3.setColumnSelectionAllowed(true);
        table3.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
        table3.setSurrendersFocusOnKeystroke(true);
        table3.setBounds(488,45,430,360);
        frame.getContentPane().remove(tablehard);
        frame.getContentPane().add(table3);
        model3.fireTableDataChanged();

        conn1.close();
        conn3.close();
        conn_pr3.close();
        conn_pr1.close();
        stmt1.close();
        stmt3.close();
        ps1.close();
        rs1.close();
        rs3.close();
        ps3.close();
    }  // end if
    else
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Cancelled!!!");

} catch ( SQLException case1){case1.printStackTrace();
} catch ( Exception case2){case2.printStackTrace();}}});
```

Comment: You are executing twice from `stmt1`, the second execute will automatically close `rs1`. It looks like the second execute should actually be done with `stmt3`.

Comment: Also, you should really split this into two methods. There is no reason to handle these two distinct operations in a single method. It will simplify your code and improve readability. I'd also suggest to look at try-with-resources because currently you are not correctly closing resources if an exception occurs. Finally: use descriptive variable name (things like `stmt1`, `stmt3`, `a1`, `a3` make it hard to follow code and will sooner introduce the exact problem you are facing).

Comment: so it would be preferable to use xxx.close(); inside the finally block?

Comment: As far as I can see from your code, you don;t need to be using 4 connections. You can do all this with conn1.

Comment: Could you give me a short example on how to use 3 lets say statements into one variable??

It would go like :

stmt1 = conn1.createStatement();
rs1 = stmt1.executeQuery(1);
rs2 = stmt1.executeQuery(2);
            .
            .
stmt1.close();

Comment: @Jaydee That actually only guaranteed tp work if you disable autocommit, otherwise you must ensure that you get holdable result sets.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Can you point me to some info about that. JDBC spec 13.1.1 states "Each Connection object can create multiple Statement objects that may be used concurrently by the program."

Comment: @Jaydee true, but JDBC assumes a 'single transaction per connection' model. When autoCommit is enabled (the default), a statement end will issue a commit. If the ResultSet is `CLOSE_CURSORS_AT_COMMIT` (default in some drivers), then a commit will close that ResultSet. Now say I iterate over a ResultSet and execute inserts from that result set with another statement of the same connection. The execute of the insert will perform a commit, then the resultset derived from another statement of the same connection will be closed. Therefor: disable auto commit with multiple statements.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Sorry, yes of course, I actually do this:-) I think I misunderstood your comment somehow. I've had a bad day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error seems in a false number ist stmt1/3.

Close first ResultSets, then Statements, then Connections.

Maybe do the four table walks in four parts. Better readable, and you may benefit from try-with-resources (as of Java 7):

```
try (ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery()) {
    while (rs.next()) {
        ...
    }
} // Automatically closes rs
```

Then this mistake would not have happened.